# Грамотно ли говорить "докоснуться"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ругаю ребенка, когда он говорит "докоснулся", а не "прикоснулся", объясняя, что такого слова нет. Но в последнее время стала замечать употребление этого слова и на телевидении, и в интернете. Может, я не права?

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса: _Холод проник ему первому под оболочку, **докоснулся** до него._ [Василий Голованов. Остров, или оправдание бессмысленных путешествий (2002)]  http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E4%EE%EA%EE%F1%ED%F3%F2%FC%F1%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Answer (score 2):

Мне пришлось поискать заданные слова в словарях, и вот какие результаты мы имеем. Первый источник [говорит](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/05/sl618812.htm), что такое слово существует и его значение определяется так:

> ДОКОСНУ́ТЬСЯ, ну́сь, не́тся, сов., ДОКАСА́ТЬСЯ, а́юсь, а́ется, несов. (Един.) Прикоснуться, дотронуться. Я звѣзд воспрянув докоснусь Челом, средь радости такия. Мур. Оды 25. А кошкѣ не могли собаки докасаться. Мур. Басни 11.

Причём я не вижу никаких данных, свидетельствующих о том, что слово вышло из употребления. Однако примеры, приведенные в словаре, говорят о том, что это всё-таки «старое» слово.

Далее мне удалось найти [такой ответ](http://ask.fm/russian/answer/56155539260). Там говорится о том, что такого слова вообще нет.

Кому верить — не знаю.

P.S. В своей речи я никогда это слово не употреблял и употреблять не собираюсь: меня ***прикоснуться*** устраивает.

Answer (score 1):

Такое слово с точки зрения русского языка является некорректным. Однако такое слово в упомянутым Вами значении действительно существовало. В Словаре русского языка XVIII в такое слово есть.

ДОКОСНУ́ТЬСЯ, ну́сь, не́тся, сов., ДОКАСА́ТЬСЯ, а́юсь, а́ется, несов. (Един.) Прикоснуться, дотронуться. Я звѣзд воспрянув докоснусь Челом, средь радости такия. Мур. Оды 25. А кошкѣ не могли собаки докасаться. Мур. Басни 11.

Словарь русского языка XVIII в."

Answer (score 1):

В современном языке желательно использовать глаголы **прикоснуться и дотронуться.**

1) Глаголы **дотронуться и прикоснуться** ― близкие по значению слова, которые могут заменять друг друга:  И вот он слушал вполуха, но не видел, как Шалико **прикоснулся к руке** Ашхен, как некогда в прошлом....[Булат Окуджава. Упраздненный театр (1989-1993)].   Толстой заглянул ему в глаза еще ласковее и тихонько **дотронулся до руки** его: [Д. С. Мережковский. Петр и Алексей (1905)].

2) Глагол **притронуться** немного изменил семантику (в значении прикоснуться используется в старых текстах): Но я не стал есть щи, **не притронулся** к гуляшу и даже боялся взглянуть на водку. [Василий Аксенов. Звездный билет // «Юность», 1961] ....однако никто из героев **не притронулся** к оружию. [Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976].   **Притронулся к руке** господина Карасева, а голос у него жирный и скрипучий, так что все слышно. [И. С. Шмелев. Человек из ресторана (1911)]

3) Глагол **докоснуться** практически  не встречается в речи (только единичные случаи), так как в языке нет необходимости в нем (**достаточно глаголов прикоснуться и дотронуться, которые имеют то же значение**).